# Obtaining a list of subtypes of generic class

Tags: c#, generics, inheritance, polymorphism

I have a generic class with many subtypes:

```
public abstract class MyClass<T> : MyBaseClass where T : class
{...}

public class MySubClassA : MyClass<A>
{...}

public class MySubClassB : MyClass<B>
{...}
```

Is there an easy way to search for subclasses of MyClass and obtain an `IEnumerable<Type>` containing MySubClassA and MySubClassB?

I have used this method before, but I am not sure how to adapt it for use with generics:

```
public static IEnumerable<Type> GetSubTypesOf(Type t, bool baseAssemblyOnly = false)
{
    List<Type> types = new List<Type>();
    Assembly[] searchAssemblies = baseAssemblyOnly
        ? new[] { Assembly.GetAssembly(t) }
        : AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies();
    foreach (Assembly a in searchAssemblies)
    {
        types.AddRange(a.GetTypes()
                        .Where(myType => myType.IsClass
                                      && !myType.IsAbstract
                                      && myType.IsSubclassOf(t)));
    }
    return types;
}
```

Comment: I am unclear why the code you posted doesn't actually work.  Seems like you would call GetSubTypesOf(typeof(MyClass<T>)) right?

Comment: I can call GetSubTypesOf(typeof(MyClass<A>)) to get MySubClassA, but I don't want to call it in the context of a particular T. I'd like to call it "for all Ts", e.g. GetSubTypesOf(typeof(MyClass<*>))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that when you pass `typeof(MyClass<>)` for the `t` parameter, you are not passing an instantiated generic type, but a generic type *definition*. This means that none of your classes would respond to `IsSubclassOf(t)`.

You can fix your code as follows:

```
List<Type> types = searchAssemblies
    .SelectMany(a => 
        a.GetTypes()
        .Where(myType => myType.IsClass && !myType.IsAbstract && HasGenericBase(myType, t))
    ).ToList();
...
private static bool HasGenericBase(Type myType, Type t) {
    Debug.Assert(t.IsGenericTypeDefinition);
    while (myType != typeof(object)) {
        if (myType.IsGenericType && myType.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == t) {
            return true;
        }
        myType = myType.BaseType;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

This is a bit complicated since you have to search the base types of a type to find one which matches the open generic type definition of `MyClass<>`. You can define a couple of helper methods:

```
public static IEnumerable<Type> BaseTypesOf(Type t)
{
    while (t != null)
    {
        yield return t;
        t = t.BaseType;
    }
}

public static Type FindGenericBaseTypeOf(Type t, Type openType)
{
    return BaseTypesOf(t)
        .FirstOrDefault(bt => bt.IsGenericType && bt.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == openType);
}
```

then you can apply them to the incoming sequence of types to search e.g.

```
var types = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetTypes()
    .Where(t => t.IsClass && !t.IsAbstract)
    .Select(t => new { Type = t, GenericBase = FindGenericBaseTypeOf(t, typeof(MyClass<>)) })
    .Where(ts => ts.GenericBase != null)
    .Select(ts => ts.GenericBase.GetGenericArguments().First())
    .ToArray();
```

Comment: The key is GetGenericTypeDefinition(): https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.getgenerictypedefinition.aspx